# Spark plug trigger with time delay

Tags: mosfet, spark

I'm currently working on a personal project where, a part of it, is having a spark plug discharge with a time delay after a signal is sent. Below is the schematic I've come up with so far but I'm not sure how to incorporate the time delay or if this circuit will even work. Currently, this schematic will work by having the capacitor store the charge for the spark plug, with a resistor of high resistance to use as a "dump tank" if needed for safety. Any advice/critiques are appreciated!

[image: Current schematic]

Comment: I don't see anything resembling an ignition coil in your circuit. How are you planning to produce the high voltage needed for your spark plug to do anything?

Comment: Have you found a mosfet that can handle 30,000 volts?

Comment: brhans. An ignition coil was an idea I had, but I'm not sure how to integrate a time delay with that. I figured using a mosfet would be best for that.

Comment: nothing remotely feasible about storing a spark to DC